# SQL Query - Select last date before timespan where no dates exists in timespan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table, I have a datetime column and a tag column. I would like to select the latest value before a timespan, if there are no values in the timespan. If there are values in the timespan, I would not like to return any values.

My query has the following input parameters:

```
@StartDate datetime
@EndDate datetime
```

The most important query results:

1. The query should not return any results if there is data between @StartDate and @EndDate
2. The query should return the latest value for each Tag before the @StartDate IF, and only if, there are no results between @StartDate and @EndDate

My issue, I have created two queries:

1. Returns the latest result before the timespan.
2. Returns all results IN the timespan.

The idea is to `SELECT [Values before the timespan] WHERE NOT EXISTS IN [Values in the timespan]`.

I have tried to join these queries to get the end result, but this is where I struggle.

---

STEPS TO REPRODUCE (SETUP):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable(id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Tag nvarchar(200) NOT NULL, StartTime datetime NOT NULL)  
DECLARE @day int, @month int, @year int

SELECT @day = 15, @month = 1, @year = 2015
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MyTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MySuperTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
SELECT @day = 16, @month = 1, @year = 2015
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MyTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MySuperTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
SELECT @day = 18, @month = 1, @year = 2015
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MyTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MySuperTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
SELECT @day = 19, @month = 1, @year = 2015
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MyTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MySuperTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
SELECT @day = 26, @month = 1, @year = 2015
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MyTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Tag, StartTime) VALUES('MySuperTag',dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1))
```

---

STEPS TO REPRODUCE (QUERY):
This should not return any values, since there are values in the timespan.

```
DECLARE @day int, @month int, @year int
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime
SELECT @day = 17, @month = 1, @year = 2015
SET @StartTime = dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1)
SET @EndTime = dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1 + 3)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, Tag, StartTime FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE StartTime < @StartTime AND Tag NOT IN ( SELECT Tag FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE (StartTime > @StartTime AND StartTime < @EndTime))) as d WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Tag, StartTime, ROW_NUMBER FROM ( SELECT Tag, StartTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS ROW_NUMBER FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE StartTime < @StartTime) AS b WHERE ROW_NUMBER = '1')
```

---

STEPS TO REPRODUCE (QUERY2):
This should produce the latest values before the timespan, since there are no values in the timespan.

```
SELECT @day = 21, @month = 1, @year = 2015
SET @StartTime = dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1)
SET @EndTime = dateadd(mm, (@year - 1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , @day - 1 + 3)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, Tag, StartTime FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE StartTime < @StartTime AND Tag NOT IN ( SELECT Tag FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE (StartTime > @StartTime AND StartTime < @EndTime))) as d WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT Tag, StartTime, ROW_NUMBER FROM ( SELECT Tag, StartTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tag ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS ROW_NUMBER FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE StartTime < @StartTime) AS b WHERE ROW_NUMBER = '1')
```

EDIT: Added "latest value for each Tag" in section about expected results.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle for Question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f58d/1/0)

Comment: Thank you AeroX. I didn't know about SQL Fiddle :)
A note about the "WHERE EXISTS" part of my query. I believe it is executed before the "WHERE Tag NOT IN" part of the query. So the records are actually brought back in to the results, which I believe is the reason why my own query is not working. But there are probably much simpler solutions that the road I'm going down...

Comment: No problem. I created it as I find SQL questions attract more answers when there is a SQL Fiddle setup

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention about the expected result. It should return the last value _for each Tag_, in case there are no values in the timespan. Sorry about that. That's why I didn't try TOP 1 solutions.

Comment: That's completely different story ;) It's better to edit initial question.

Comment: I know, and I'm Sorry about that.. I have edited the question, written a note in the bottom of the question about the edit, and made a comment about the edit below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my revised answer for the modified question:

```
SELECT [A].* FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [A]
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT [Tag], MAX([StartTime]) AS [StartTime]
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
  WHERE [StartTime] < @StartTime
  GROUP BY [Tag]
) AS B ON ([A].[Tag] = [B].[Tag] AND [A].[StartTime] = [B].[StartTime])
WHERE
  [A].[StartTime] < @StartTime AND
  0 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
  )
;
```

The joined subquery works out the latest date for each tag before the `@StartTime` and joins back to it's self so that the full row can be returned (with the `id`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution! I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation(yet).

There was another issue in my question that I forgot. It should check if there are values in the timespan per Tag. But your solution was very easy to edit in order for it to work with my real world problem. And I see no reason to edit it, since it answers the question I have asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable t
WHERE StartTime < @start
  AND id = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 mt.id FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.Tag = t.Tag ORDER BY StartTime DESC)
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE StartTime >= @start AND StartTime <= @end)
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Comment: After working through the typos, correcting GT/LT, correcting AND/OR. I still am not able to produce the correct result from your suggested answer. After correcting to the best of my knowledge, it returns 8 NULL rows or 8 rows of duplicate datetime, not containing payload information (Tag in this example).

Comment: Give me some time to prepare fiddle for you.

Comment: Updated to meet new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be roughly what you are looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE
  [StartTime] < @StartTime AND
  0 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
    WHERE [StartTime] BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
  )
ORDER BY [StartTime] DESC;
```

The `0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) ...)` bit causes the query to return no data when there is data between the `@StartTime` and `@EndTime`.  The rest of the query is then just selecting the first row before the `@StartTime`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f58d/10/0)

Comparison of query plans for `0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) ...)` vs `EXISTS(SELECT 1 ...)`
[image: Query Plan Comparison]

Comment: You could SELECT 1 and EXISTS instead of COUNT which will be much faster in case of huge dataset. Checkout my answer.

Comment: @tvelykyy In my experience it depends on indexing etc. When running both methods, they produce near identical query plans. The difference being where the SORT operation happens. My method resulted in a `TopN Sort` being done as the last operation in the plan. Your method resulted in an extra sort step being added before the nested loop.